# Regular expression with specific characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regular expression which would look like for ex: `H005-2007-652764`

```
First char should start with `H`
5th and 10th char should be `-`
Remaining all should be digits
```

Comment: Please show your efforts. That is the least you can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements are perhaps not totally complete, but if I assume that you only want six digit characters at the end, something like the regex `/H\d{3}-\d{4}-\d{6}/` would work.  You can see it working [here](https://regexr.com/5a9qp) or in the snippet below:

```js
const text = 'nonsense nonsense lorem ipsum H005-2007-652764 and then more nonsense';

const regex = /H\d{3}-\d{4}-\d{6}/;

console.log(text.match(regex));
```